# Xinerama and OpenGL on multiple Matrox devices while using JOGL

Tags: java, linux, centos, jogl, xorg

I'm encountering a problem while using 2 Matrox Extio F2408 devices.
I run a Centos 5.0 system with 5 monitors, 4 connected to the first Extion device, the fifth to the second.
Xinerama mode is enabled.

All is fine but when we open an application feature using OpenGL (implemented in Java with JOGL) the CPU
jumps in 100% and the memory consumption of our application increases dramatically. The application freezes like this.

I have this problem only when we connect both Extio devices in Xinerama mode. With only one device in Xinerama,
or with both of them but without Xinerama there is no problem.

I have updated to the latest official matrox video card driver but this was not a solution.

Could you point me in the right direction in debugging or solving this problem?